# PDOException:could not find driver

Tags: php, sql-server, macos, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have installed mssql driver in my MAC for php7.1

I checked my mssql connection too.

```
TDSVER=8.0 tsql -H yyy.yyy.yy.yy -U xx -D testphp -p 1433 -P xxx
```

Now when I try

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

I get following exception.Why do I still get this error?[1] I have installed driver and all

```
brew install msodbcsql
brew install mssql-tools
brew install autoconf
sudo pear config-set php_ini `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"` system
 sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

{1]

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
      could not find driver (SQL: create table "migrations" ("id" int identity pr  
      imary key not null, "migration" nvarchar(191) not null, "batch" int not nul  
      l))                                                                          

      [PDOException]         
      could not find driver
```

When I locate pdo_mssql driver i see following entries.

```
/usr/include/php/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h
/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.7_19/lib/php/.registry/.channel.pecl.php.net/pdo_sqlsrv.reg
/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.7_19/lib/php/doc/pdo_sqlsrv
```

Answer (score 0):

Please create one file with phpinfo() function in your location and check whether the driver connection is enabled for mssql.

Answer (score 0):

Run `brew options php71`, and then you will see an option like `--with-mssql`. Reinstall with `brew install php71 --with-mssql`.